# Where can I buy digital copies of this version of Kenzen Robo Daimidaler?

Tags: kenzen-robo-daimidaler

**NSFW Warning: This is not hentai but there are NSFW images from an ecchi manga below that some may find offensive (non-consensual lewd scenes). You have been warned.**

I have the digital (Book Walker) and physical copies of *Kenzen Robo Daimidarā OGS*. However, there seems to be a different version of the manga. On these images I found in a certain scanlation site, there are pages and panels that are different from the digital and physical copies that I have.

Examples:

- A page on the digital/physical volume of *Kenzen Robo Daimidarā OGS Vol. 4*.

  > [image]
- The same page but somehow, with different panels.

  > [image]

Does anyone maybe know where I can buy/read these chapters legally? Or is the only option buying old copies of the *Fellows!/Harta* volumes where the manga was serialized? I tried finding these chapters among the list of legal sources [here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/922/how-can-i-tell-if-a-site-is-legal) with no luck.

Comment: You mean the above is tankobon and the below is the magazine ver? Then, it means that the panels were rearranged/redrawn at the time of tankobo-ization, so most probably buying the physical magazine is the only possibility.

Comment: @sundowner I see, thanks for replying. They seem too clean to be scanned from physical pages, though, so I'm hoping that maybe the magazines are at least available digitally. Do you maybe know if older Harta volumes (starting from Feb 2013) are available digitally?

Comment: The [official tweet](https://twitter.com/hartamanga/status/1272495897188827137) says digital version is available from 2020, so I guess the answer is no. Back in those days, illegal scanners did such a great job that surpasses today's legal digital copies.... Maybe not realistic for you, but physical copies seem available on amazon.co.jp.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a revision made between the serialised and published chapter (which seems likely since your second image has page number 415 in the corner and [volume 4](https://bookwalker.jp/de8f350483-2a5c-494f-a242-516d74ead086/) only has 187 pages) then you would have to source the print issues of the magazine.

Digital issues of Harta do not get removed from sale after a brief window (unlike most other Kadokawa group magazines), however the digital edition only began with [Issue 75](https://bookwalker.jp/de4a12fd8b-152e-4332-a1d2-fb530fb77b97/) in June 2020, whereas Daimidaler OGS ran from [2013 to 2016](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%81%A5%E5%85%A8%E3%83%AD%E3%83%9C_%E3%83%80%E3%82%A4%E3%83%9F%E3%83%80%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, sorry for the late reply. I uploaded these two pictures to the internet before (f*pservic*). Both sites I found seem to be down now; they were pirated sites (Bezald and marumaru).

But if you can find and search the Korean name (건전로봇 다이미다라 OGS) and Korean translation of this manga, I'm sure you'll find those versions online.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. Did you mean that the different arrangement is from the official Korean translation? However, the panels in the question are both in Japanese though.